# Publish Windows form application how change the installation path

Tags: winforms, clickonce, publish, windows

I have built one windows forms application and I published for client installation. While installing the setup file, it should ask the user to select the installation directory path; instead, it's installing in default path as below :

```
C:\Users\Mysys_t\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\434YBBVC.Z2H\TNYPR09N.1JZ
```

Is there any settings to do this, so that, while installing, user is able to select the installation directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be achieved by

Creating an MSI Package for C# Windows Application Using a Visual Studio Setup Project

pls follow the link below :

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1492b1/creating-an-msi-package-for-C-Sharp-windows-application-using-a-v/

Answer (score 1):

In general, the answer is no.  See a [related MSDN forums discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f9ab0208-6edc-4888-a2a4-6cbc4b3ba4b7/clickonce-deployment-with-custom-install-directory?forum=winformssetup) among other online references that explains why: ClickOnce was designed to automatically manage installation directories to prevent deployment collisions.

Now...the referenced MSDN forums discussion also links to one way to possibly work around this.  Certainly anything is possible with some ingenuity and work (e.g. publishing a setup wrapper with ClickOnce to leverage ClickOnce's auto updates but use indirection to control where your actual app ultimately gets installed); but this is not possible using ClickOnce "straightforwardly".