# Change Published Project Install Directory in Windows8.1

Tags: c#, windows

I am trying to change the default installation directory of my projects when I publish them but I seem to have no choice over where the published setup.exe actually puts the program. It seems after setup.exe running and application installed, all the processed files are under the folder of `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\` (Something like that, I dont remember the exact directory as it is very long). This is not what i want as I installed the program in the `C:\Program Files\` but all the log files go to the `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\`. This is really really annoying.

The application I published is C# Windows Form Application

And I have looked through online and found that somebody suggested to create an MSI package for C# Windows Application Using a Visual Studio Setup Project instead of publishing the program:

[Publish Windows form application how change the installation path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25902948/publish-windows-form-application-how-change-the-installation-path)

It is supposed that the above website can solve this problem. Are there any other suggestions to solve this redirection problem after publishing the C# Windows Form Application? Thank you.

Comment: If you're using ClickOnce as it seems, this is by design. Why is this problematic for you?

Comment: My issue is not related to the ClickOnce, it is that log files are redirecting to "C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\" after installation of program and running, which is not what I need. I need them to be located under the folder of "C:\Program Files\"

Comment: Do they need to be in %ProgramFiles% per se, or just in a predictable directory?

Comment: Yes, they need to be in %ProgramFiles% and any log files generated by the installed program should be in %ProgramFiles% rather than "C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\".

Comment: Show parts of the code how you create the logs. %ProgramFiles% is definitely not a good location for app log files.

Comment: I have used the Application.StartupPath as the location folder in the code. When I run the Program using Visual Studio, it correctly go to the folder I want. But when I published it, it go to a folder under  C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\ , which seems like a virtual store location.

Comment: @DavidAlex Use `Path.Combine(    Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData),
    "MyCompanyName")` instead of `Application.StartupPath`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the *Publish* funtion in Visual Studio, you are creating click-once publication. This type of deployment has relatively fixed rules and not everything can be configured. It allways installs into an obfuscated folder under windows user profile. It is similar to the fact, that you cannot change location where windows-store modern apps are installed under Windows 8.1.

You can create MSI setup project for your app - but in Visual Studio 2012 this type of project is missing and it was re-introduced againg in Visuals Studio 2013. There you can specify install folder. You can also use Install Shield Lite with Visual Studio 2012.

You wrote:

> This is not what i want as I installed the program in the C:\Program
>   Files\

It is not possible to install ClickOnce application using Publish button in Visual Studio into `C:\Program Files\`.

If you have just problem with the location of your log files, you need to specify a different folder within your application code. Make sure that user, who is running your app, has write access to that folder - it should be in some user's profile folder or in a public folder. Avoid `%ProgramFiles%` as a folder for your log files - it is not a good practice.

Instead of `Application.StartupPath` you should use path accessible to all users including non-admin, like:

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData),"MyCompanyName")
```

Comment: I have already fixed the location directory in my application code as I tried many ways. Although this fixed coding way works I don't think it is a good solution. Is it possible to use Install Shield Lite with Visual Studio 2013 as my company has already bought Visual Studio Professional 2013.

Comment: Thank you Vojtěch Dohnal for your help, I would like to ask you whether "avoid C:\Program Files\ as a folder" is a potential bug for Windows 8.1 as it works for Windows XP and maybe Windows 7.

Comment: At least since XP it's best practice to not write anything during program execution to ProgramFiles as users have no write access there. In windows 7 and 8 there is the so called VirtualStore that as long as UAC is active will be redirected to C:\Users\<username>AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files though that seems not to be what happens at your pc as the folder is different. Still user logs should be in appdata of the user system logs in programdata if you want to follow microsofts best practice

Comment: Yes, XP is nice for developers but Windows 7 and 8 introduced this kind of VIrtualStore I dont like. Very unconvenient to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use InstallShield to create installation wizards/Setup.

[Here's the free version for Visual Studio](http://learn.flexerasoftware.com/content/IS-EVAL-InstallShield-Limited-Edition-Visual-Studio)